# When did my Mac's HD last sleep?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook, sleep

Is there any app or log that says when my MacBook Pro's hard drive last went into sleep mode? I ask because each night when I close the MBP's lid without being plugged into a power source, the power light goes into its snooze rhythm but the battery is half-drained by the next morning. It certainly looks like it is asleep, but the power drain seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: +1 My macbook does the same thing. I thought this was normal.

Comment: My macbook does the same thing. I'm going to assume you're running OS X 10.6, since the battery-drain while sleeping seemed to get much worse for me after upgrading.

Comment: Same here. My Toshiba can sleep for almost a week, but my OS X 10.6 MacBook hardly manages one night.

Answer (score 1):

I put my macbook to sleep and checked system.log file.  Then I used mdtuil to reindex spotlight (which prevents the hard dive from sleeping while its indexing) then I put it to sleep again. I compared the log entries from both sleeps and there was no difference. So it looks like this can't be done using OS X logs.

Read through this Apple support page [Mac OS X: Why your Mac might not sleep or stay in sleep mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776) and see if anything there helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't explain why you're losing quite so much power, but don't forget that the battery will drain whilst the Mac is asleep anyway at around 1% an hour.

Comment: Yes, but my battery is way passed its prime. Its condition in System Info is "Replace Now" even though the cycle count is only 351.